# Chromedriver + Selenium cannot send 's' key

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Using Python 3.7.4, Selenium 3.141.0, Chromedriver 78 and Chrome 78.

I'm am trying to automate login to a webpage but when I send keys to the inputs in the form it sends all the characters but the 's' letter.

```
input = form_element.find_element_by_xpath(password_xpath)
input.send_keys("password")
```

It only writes "paword". I've seen this issue in other querstions but the Chromedriver version was old. Also I tried with "\s" but it writes "\".

Didn't find any documentation of this. I tried with Chrome 77 + Chromedriver 77, same result.
Have anyone had this problem before? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to identify the *password* field and subsequently send a *character sequence*, possibly some [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) or [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) call is in progress. Hence the issue.

---

### Solution

To locate and send a *character sequence* to the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "password_css"))).send_keys("password")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "password_xpath"))).send_keys("password")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap `send_keys` in a method to slowly send keys with a wait between each character press. This might help slow down the key send and allow any Javascript events on the field to fire in time, without interrupting your key send:

```
def slowly_send_keys(field, text):
    for c in text:
        field.send_keys(c)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

You can call this as such:

```
input = form_element.find_element_by_xpath(password_xpath)
slowly_send_keys(input, "password")
```

We are just waiting 0.1s between each key press here. Sometimes Selenium sends keys very quickly, and not all keystrokes get registered, so this solution is meant to work around that potential issue.

Mentioned in Debanjan's solution above, invoking `WebDriverWait` on the password field should also help resolve your issue -- I wanted to provide an alternative to `send_keys` in case that was part of the issue here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You Can `Send Keys` By Adding Wait There Because Some Time `Element Not Clickable` And Also Make Sure That Your Are Giving Right `Xpath`!

If You Don't Give Right `XPATH` It Will Also Give You Error

For Correct `Xpath` you can use selector gadget in chrome

Well If You Are Give Right `XPATH` Then:

Try This Code!

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as 

input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "YOUR XPATH"))).send_keys("Your Password")
```

You Can Also Add Wait After Character Here Is The Way!

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as 

input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "YOUR XPATH")))

for p in input:
    input.send_keys(p)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```